# Using a LED as indicator for 9VAC and "borrowing" a 5V-ground does not work. Why?

Tags: voltage, led

The power supply in a Commodore 64 has two voltages: 9VAC and 5VDC. The 9V comes straight from the transformer while the 5V comes from a 7805 and some filtering within the PSU, before outputting on the cable.

Just for the sake of testing, I hooked up a LED and 1k resistor to one of the two 9V-pins, and the other end to the GND-pin (from the 5V-net).

However, that did not work at all. I thought that even if the 9VAC-net does not have a ground, using another ground point in the same supply would work, but obviously it does not.

Question: why doesn't it work?

(What does work is hooking up to the other 9VAC-pin instead of GND, but then the reverse voltage will be too high for the LED [as I recently learned in another thread] so I need another diode in series to protect it, but I'd rather use only a resistor + LED)

[image]

Comment: Here's the first result on google image search for the Commodore 64 power supply schematic. Trace the return path of your LED: http://www.zimmers.net/anonftp/pub/cbm/schematics/computers/c64/c64extps.gif

Comment: Right, there is no return path since the transformer obviously has two secondary windings.

Comment: you can use a tiny bridge rectifier to get DC from your AC. go ahead and add a smoothing cap for fun; a baby PSU.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 9 VAC connections are not connected to the common ground of the power supply. Therefore if you wish to use the 9VAC circuit you will need to connect the LED across the two 9 VAC pins. An LED should not be directly used on AC since it generally cannot tolerate the reverse voltage. If you place a regular diode (e.g. 1N4001) in series with the LED and the dropping resistor, you will have a working solution. If the slight flicker of the LED bothers you, you can also add a filter capacitor. A 47 uF electrolytic capacitor should be more than sufficient.